# How to hide a tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

I'm working on website using CRM (drupal) and the tooltip for mobile i don't know how to hide it when i click on it again this is the website http://www.cfb.it in the section of servizi the tooltip work fine for the desktop, but when I try to access the website from the phone (I tried iphone and samsung) and click on it, the tooltip appear but I cannot hide it back again once I click it's stay.

Here is the jquery code for this tooltip, I don't know what is missing.

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

  function tooltipInit() {
              var tooltip = jQuery('.tooltip'),
                  target = jQuery('.icon'),
                  arrow = jQuery('.arrow-down'),
                  mobile = jQuery(window).width() < 960,
                  desktop = jQuery(window).width() > 960
              if (mobile) {
                  jQuery(".overview:odd").addClass('pull-left');
                  target.click(function() {
                      target.css({
                          "background-position": "top"
                      });
                      jQuery(this).css({
                          "background-position": "bottom"
                      });
                      tooltip.removeClass('visible');
                      arrow.removeClass('visible');
                      jQuery(this).siblings('.tooltip, .arrow-down, .details').addClass('visible');
                       $this = $(this);
                       $this.parents('.icons').find('.details').removeClass('mobile-show');
                       $this.find('.details').addClass('mobile-show');
                  });
                  tooltip.click(function() {
                      jQuery(this).removeClass('visible');
                      jQuery(this).siblings('.arrow-down').removeClass('visible');
                      jQuery(this).siblings('.icon').css({
                          "background-position": "top"
                      });
                  });
                  target.unbind('mouseenter');
                  target.unbind('mouseleave');
              }
              if (desktop) {
                  jQuery('.pull-left').removeClass('pull-left');
                  target.css({
                      "background-position": "top"
                  })
                  tooltip.removeClass('visible');
                  arrow.removeClass('visible');
                  target.bind('mouseenter', function() {
                      jQuery(this).siblings('.tooltip, .arrow-down').addClass('visible');
                      jQuery(this).css({
                          "background-position": "bottom"
                      });
                      var removeTooltip = function() {
                          tooltip.removeClass('visible');
                          arrow.removeClass('visible');
                      };
                      target.bind('mouseleave', removeTooltip);
                      target.bind('mouseleave', function() {
                          jQuery(this).css({
                              "background-position": "top"
                          });
                      });
                  });
              }
          }
          jQuery(window).on("resize", tooltipInit);
          jQuery(document).on("ready", tooltipInit);
```

This tooltip is similar to this one in this website http://visia.themes.tf/
I will appreciate your help please

Answer (score 1):

Hello Please use below code to track if devide is mobile device or not then execute your code

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the code above is related to navigator menu , and away from the question little bit, also it's lead to the same result as the previous one. The problem is not check if the device mobile or not the problem is i am not able to hide the tooltip after i click on it from mobile